# How can I set a relationship with a condition in Strapi

Tags: node.js, strapi

How can I set a relationship with a condition in a [model](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-alpha.x/guides/models.html#how-to-create-a-model)([strapi](https://strapi.io))? 
For eg Post has-many: comments i wish to have one latest active comment

Comment: Hello! Not sure to understand what you are trying to do, can you precise please.

Comment: just want the last comment within post response